# Retrieving data from a SQL database to VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?
Very basic level of Visual Basic experience.

Im trying to retrieve the ORDERID, ORDERDATE and CUSTOMERID from the database provided and show them in a dataGridView?

```
Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection
con1.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=msdaora;Data Source=orabis;User Id=112221800;Password=112221800;"

'Dim con1 As New SqlConnection("Provider=msdaora;Data Source=orabis;User Id=112221800;Password=112221800;")
con1.Open()
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select ORDERID, ORDERDATE AND CUSTOMERID from CUSORDER", con1)

Dim ada1 As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
ada1.Fill(ds1)
ViewDeliverys.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)

con1.Close()
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle? Add it as a tag (or confirm and I will)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `OleDbConnection` whith a `SqlCommand`(SQL-Server). Which rdbms are you using?

This works for SQL-Server:

```
Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ORDERID, ORDERDATE AND CUSTOMERID from CUSORDER", con)
        Dim table = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(table)
        ViewDeliverys.DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    End Using
End Using
```

Edit: Here's the `OleDb` version:

```
Using con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ORDERID, ORDERDATE AND CUSTOMERID from CUSORDER", con)
        Dim table = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(table)
        ViewDeliverys.DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Using An Oracle SQL Developer? So will need the oleDbConnection?

Comment: Dim con1 As New SqlConnection
        con1.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=orabis;User Id=112221800;Password=112221800;"

        con1.Open()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet

        Using con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString:=)
            Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ORDERID, ORDERDATE AND CUSTOMERID from CUSORDER", con)
                Dim table = New DataTable()
                da.Fill(table)
                ViewDeliverys.DataGridView1.DataSource = table
            End Using
        End Using

Comment: So this is the whole thing? Sorry im at a real beginner stage. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @112221: I've shown the complete code to get the data and use it as DataSource for a `DataGridView`. Note that it's not necessary to open/close a connection with `DataAdapter.Fill`.

Comment: AHHHHH!!!!! Still getting the provider error.. Thanks for your help, I'll try figure it out some how.

Comment: @112221: Then it's a problem with your connection-string. Have a look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb

Comment: Fixed the connection string but now getting a different error..  Private Function OleDbConnectionStringBuilder() As String
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

Comment: The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: @112221: Seems to be a different question. I don't see where you  use a `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`.  You can use one to create ypou connection string, e.g.:  `Dim builder = New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder()
        ' set all properties here '`. Then use `builder.ToString` to get the connection-string.

Answer (score 0):

What Database are you using SQL Sever or MS Access?
If you are uing SQL Server use SQL Connection then OleDBConnection on MS Access.

For the correct connection string check it on:

http://www.connectionstrings.com

Check also this tutorial from:

[http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-sqldataadapter](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-sqldataadapter.htm)

And also Replace your query from:

```
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select ORDERID, ORDERDATE AND CUSTOMERID from CUSORDER", con1)
```

where `ORDERDATE AND CUSTOMERID` will throws you an error

Change it to:

```
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select ORDERID, ORDERDATE,CUSTOMERID from CUSORDER", con1)
```